# android-sdk\docs\reference missing

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc, android-sdk-2.1

While creating my JavaDoc for an Android project, I'd like to include a link to the offical online reference of Android when clicking on Android classes/packages.

As far as I know most people do this, using a linkoffline, providing the package list of android.
But I there is **no such file/directory *android-sdk\docs\reference***

Current ant file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project
    name="api docs"
    basedir="."
    default="doc" >

    <target
        name="doc"
        description="my docs" >

        <javadoc
            access="private"
            classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-4\android.jar;.\libs\admob-sdk-android.jar"
            destdir="docs"
            doctitle="Testing the Title"
            packagenames="*"
            sourcepath="src"
            stylesheetfile="C:\Users\Johannes Staehlin\development\android\UITheme\doc\stylesheet.css"
            use="true"
            verbose="on" >

            <link
                href="http://d.android.com/reference"
                offline="true"
                packagelistloc="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\docs\reference" > // <--- DOES NOT EXIST
            </link>
        </javadoc>
    </target>

</project>
```

BTW: I still get some warnings like

```
cannot find symbol
  [javadoc] public class MeetingListFragment extends Fragment {
```

Comment: have you fix that yet.... i still facing almost the same problem on windows 64 bit

Comment: No, not really... at least I get the stack trace now before facing this error. Just re-installed everything

Answer (score 1):

The "docs"-folder will be created when you install the "Documentation for Android SDK" in the SDK Manager.

The documentation seems to be available for the latest Android version only.

Answer (score 0):

You must install documentation for one of the Android APIs using the Android SDK Manager.